# multiple ajax call on page load in single page application

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new in front end development I need to ask one question regarding performance of page rendering

I am creating single page application I used multiple Ajax calls to get data so I can manipulate with it to increase the performance

can multiple Ajax call damage the performance  if yes then why and how can i make it faster 
i.e

```
$.ajax({
        type: "",
        url: "",
        dataType: "",
        success: ""
      });

$.ajax({
        type: "",
        url: "",
        dataType: "",
        success: ""
      });

$.ajax({
        type: "",
        url: "",
        dataType: "",
        success: ""
      });

$.ajax({
        type: "",
        url: "",
        dataType: "",
        success: ""
      });

....
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Whit AJAX you can do one big call and return all the data needed in your app, but may be you are getting not necessary data until the user do some action in the page... for this case is better to do more AJAX calls... but this is particularly for each app... do what you think is better for your app... to have multiple AJAX calls in a same page is not a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each call will have an overhead of making a network round trip, connecting to the server and downloading the response, hence resulting in network waste. Best solution would be to combine multiple ajax calls into one call
Take a look at deferred callback batch execution

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: yes you are right but does it make hug impact on performance after combining the Ajax request  currently my total number of Ajax call is closed to 20